# My Open GL View is not matching my code

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm having a problem setting my camera view, and projection view. I've checked everything multiple times, and I've gone through many different tutorials, yet I still can not figure out why the display does not match my code. I set the eye view to (0,0,-5) and I have it looking towards (0,0,0). The coordinates of my triangle are set to be a right triangle, yet when executed, my triangle is very skewed. I don't know if it's my camera view or my projection view, but something is very wrong.  In addition, I followed and copied the code from another tutorial making a cube. My code matched the tutorial, yet my cube wasn't a cube at all, but rather a very odd 2D-like shape. But, the cube isn't drawn in the code I posted, so I'm not really worried about that right now.

Here's my code:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);
        MyRenderer=new MyGlRenderer();
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(MyRenderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}

Triangle mTriangle;
Cube mCube;

public class MyGlRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mRotationMatrix=new float[16];
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config){
        //GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClearDepthf(1f);

        mTriangle= new Triangle();
        mCube=new Cube();

    }
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused){

        float random1=(float)Math.random();
        float random2=(float)Math.random();
        float random3=(float)Math.random();
        GLES20.glClearColor(random1, random2, random3, 1.0f);

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        float[] scratch = new float[16];
        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 1, 0, -1.0f);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        //Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
        mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        //mCube.draw(scratch);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height){
        GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
        float ratio=(float) width/height;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1f, 1, 25);
    }

}
```

Here's the triangle code:

```
    public class Triangle{

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX=3;
    float triangleCoords[]={
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // top
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
             1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f  // bottom right
    };

    int mProgram;
    float color[] = { 0.13671875f, 0.66953125f, 0.72265625f, 1.0f };

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"+
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position =vPosition*uMVPMatrix;" +
            "}";

        private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

    public Triangle(){
        ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                triangleCoords.length*4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer=bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader=loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader=loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }

    public int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
        int shader=GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }

    static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 3;
    static final int vertexCount = 3;


    public void draw(float[]mvpMatrix){
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        int mPositionHandle= GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                      vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        int mColorHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color,0);
        int mMVPMatrixHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix,0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

Here's the Cube code(although I don't have my cube drawn in this code):

```
    public class Cube {

int mProgram;
float color[] = { 0.13671875f, 0.66953125f, 0.72265625f, 1.0f };

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"+
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position =vPosition*uMVPMatrix;" +
        "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX=3;

private float vertices[]={

        0,0,0,// top left front
        0,-1,0,//bottom left front
        1,-1,0,//bottom right front
        1,0,0,//top right front

        0,0,-1,//top left back
        0,-1,-1,//bottom left back
        1,-1,-1,//bottom right back
        1,0,-1//top right back


};

private FloatBuffer vertBuff;

private short pIndex[]={
        1,0,5, 1,5,2, 1,2,0, 
        3,0,2, 3,2,7, 3,7,0, 
         4,7,5, 4,5,0, 4,0,7,
        6,7,2, 6,2,5, 6,5,7 
};

private ShortBuffer pBuff;

public Cube(){
    ByteBuffer bBuff= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);
    bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertBuff=bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    vertBuff.put(vertices);
    vertBuff.position(0);

    ByteBuffer pbBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length*2);
    pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    pBuff=pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
    pBuff.put(pIndex);
    pBuff.position(0);

    int vertexShader=loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader=loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
}

public int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
    int shader=GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    return shader;
}

static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 8;
static final int vertexCount = 8;

public void draw(float[]mvpMatrix){
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);
    int mPositionHandle= GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                  vertexStride, vertBuff);
    int mColorHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color,0);
    int mMVPMatrixHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix,0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexCount);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
    }
```

Comment: For the cube, you should use glDrawElements for which you can give pBuff (indices) as parameter. Also vertex count is length of these indices. And draw mode is GL_TRIANGLES.

Comment: Multiplying the vectors from the left in the vertex shader is fairly unusual. Perfectly legal if your matrices are set up that way, but it's not what most people do. From the way I read your matrix setup code, I think it might be backwards in your case. Try multiplying from the right (`uMVPMatrix*vPosition`), and see if that works better.

Comment: @harism well now my "cube" is a 3-D shape, just not a cube, and more like a trapezoid.I don't think my vertices are wrong, but for some reason it's just not looking like a cube at all. And I'm now trying to change the eye view, but even after changing the view from 0 to 30 for x,y,and z, it changes nothing.

Comment: @RetoKoradi well that definitely changed something, but it didn't seem to work. It made my "cube" into a lop-sided pyramid. I'm not sure which way is correct, but they both have different results. The one thing that was the same is that changing the eye view coordinates does nothing to the orientation or view.

Comment: Within cube vertex shader you expect to receive vec4 (vPosition) but on code you feed it only with three values (vec3). You could try changing vertex shader vPosition to vec3 , and , where you multiply vPosition with MVP matrix give it vec4(vPosition, 1.0) .

Comment: vertexStride seems incorrectly calculated also. GL_FLOAT takes 4 bytes - but current implementation uses COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 8 to calculate stride. This quite likely messes glVertexAttribPointer call.

Comment: @harism: Declaring the attribute as `vec4` and only passing 3 coordinates in is fine. The components that are not passed in will automatically receive 0.0 for x/y/z and 1.0 for w.

Comment: After changing the vertext Stride to COORDS_PER_VERTEX*4, vec4 to vec3 and making gl_Position =vec4(vPosition,1.0). I get a square in the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thanks, I never noticed about such default values before. Good to know!